# How to generate tint, shade and shadow colors in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, android, google-material-design

I am trying to make an app icon by following the guidelines given [here](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons) in Adobe Illustrator, but I am unable to figure out how to generate the colors for tint, shade and shadow. Can anyone help me with that?

Thank You.

Comment: Hi Aakaash, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two easy ways:

1. Use the Color Guide palette. Open the Color Guide options to control the number of steps and variation between steps.
   [image: Color Guide palette in illustrator]
2. There is a script called "[Add Highlight And Shadow Swatches](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/)" that does exactly that. You'd need to adjust the values manually in the script, though.

Comment: I tried the Color Guide but it makes the shades by adding black to the base color. But according to what Google has given in material design [Image](http://i.imgur.com/Diuxrip.jpg)

I need to make Blue overlapped with Indigo 900 20%. I am not able to get that.

Comment: Then I think you will have to do it manually. make a square, overlap it with the blue as specified and make a swatch from the resulting color.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Illustrator calculates the Tints and Shades, but when I use these swatches for suggesting 3d objects, sometimes the shades look too grey and light.

[image: Shade looking too grey]

So far, the best I found is double clicking on the Fill-square, switching to HSL mode and sliding the brightness slider down.

[image: Using the Fill-square and the Brightness slider]

This give me usually better results:

[image]